# c#: Input string not in correct format error when converting list of type string to int

Tags: c#, sqlite

using winforms , c# and sqlite

I was trying to convert a list which is of type string to int using the following:

```
 List<int> ints = list2.ConvertAll<int>(int.Parse);
```

Note: I declared the list outside of the method before writing the code above as follows:

```
 List<int> ints = new List<int>();
```

I want to use this list to populate columns in sqlite like this:

```
 sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 't2' (YYMM int32, MinDate int32, MaxDate int32, TotalTrans int32, DebitTrans int32, AMOUNTINDOCUMENTCURREN int32 );";

        sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        sqlite_cmd.CommandText = " DELETE FROM t2";
        sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO t2 (YYMM, MinDate, MaxDate, TotalTrans, DebitTrans, AMOUNTINDOCUMENTCURREN ) VALUES (@b1, @b2, @b3, @b4, @b5, @b6)";
        sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b1", 6);  // dummy initial values 
        sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b2", 878);
        sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b3", 56);
        sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b4", 6);
        sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b5", 546);
        sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b6", 565);

        for (int i = 0; i < NumList2Values; i += 6) // Filling SQlite table rows and columns with values from list2
        {
            sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b1", ints[i]);
            sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b2", ints[i + 1]);
            sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b3", ints[i + 2]);
            sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b4", ints[i + 3]);
            sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b5", ints[i + 4]);
            sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b6", ints[i + 5]);
            sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

The problem is that I get this Error when compiling the program:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to redesign your code so that you have a **List** of **Integer** values.

For Example:

```
private void TestRoutine(List<string> section2, int[] pos2,
  int[] len2, string[] val2)
{
  var list2 = new List<int>();
  foreach (var line in section2)
  {
    for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++)
    {
      int numValue = 0;
      val2[k] = line.Substring(pos2[k], len2[k]);
      int.TryParse(val2[k], out numValue);
      list2.Add(numValue);
    }
  }
}
```

You could also add some code to check and ensure `TryParse` succeeds before adding it.

Comment: I'm getting an error saying local variable numValue cant be passed into list2 . I then made numValue a property and then I got another error saying that I cant put a property in .TryParse method. Im guessing I would have to make it global?

Comment: It cannot be a Property, but there should be nothing wrong with it being a local variable. Try moving numValue inside for loop and initialize it like in the updated example.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to use `ConvertAll` like that. But you can do this:

```
list2.Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToList();
```

and that will give you a `List<int>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `ConvertAll`, here's how you would use it.

```
List<int> ints = list2.ConvertAll(x => int.Parse(x));
```